# In how many ways he can invite atleast one of his friends for dinner if a man has $7$ friends?

Tags: permutations, combinations

> A man has 7 friends.In how many ways he can invite atleast one of his friends for dinner?

Options

a)$63$   b)$120$   c)$127$   d)$256$

My approach:

@Edit

There are $2$ ways whether he invites or not invites.
I am thinking of $2^7-1$ ways because  $1$st friend can be invited in $7C1$ times  2nd friend can be invited in $7C1$ times etc and also only 1 condition where no one is invited have to be subtracted.

> Is it right?

Comment: Hint: How many ways are there to choose 1 friend, 2 friends, ..., 7 friends?

Comment: @JosephZambrano I edited.This is what i think

Comment: @JosephZambrano I think i made it by your hint.Thanku :)

Comment: That general idea is not too far away. Let consider all strings of length 7 consisting of 0s and 1s. For example, 0000000 or 1101011. A 0 in the i-th position will denote that the i-th friend is not invited. Similarly, a 1 in the i-th position will denote that the i-th friend is invited. How many different strings are there? Why is 0000000 not to be counted?

Comment: Because we want alt least 1 and not none.Therefore 0000000 will not be counted.Similarly for my question.The general idea:Whether he invites or not invites there are 2 ways and he have to select 1 friend from 7 friends at dinner.you made my brain work. :)

Comment: $2^7-1$ is certainly correct but it seems your logic is off a bit. Using my previous comment, each position (corresponding to an invitation) has two possibilities: 0 or 1. It follows that there are $2^7$ strings. However, the one with all zeros, 0000000, cannot be counted because we have to invite at least one friend. Therefore the answer is $2^7-1$. The other method, you would add 7C1+7C2+...+7C7 to get to the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The contrary is "in how many way can he invite no body ?"

Notice that if $\Omega$ represent all the way he can invite his friends, then $|\Omega|=2^7$. But actually, the question is not very well asked.

Answer (score 2):

Every friend corresponds to a binary decision variable, to invite or not invite. If we write a binary number (ordered sequence of binary digits), letting 0 mean "do not invite" and 1 mean "invite", then the number will be 7 binary digits long and therefore hold $2^7$ different numbers. However in order to have "at least one friend" invited, the number corresponding to inviting no one: 0000000 is "forbidden", leaving us with $2^7-1 = 127$ configurations left.

Answer (score 1):

I advise that you read up on the *choose function* or *Binomial coefficient* ${n \choose k}$ , which counts the number of ways to pick a subset of $0\le k\le n$ objects from a set of $n$ distinguishable objects. In this case, you should think of the man's friends as distinguishable objects as they are not all alike. In other combinatorial problems, such as some ball and urn problems, the objects are indistinguishable and so such an approach is not appropriate.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient